# How to make Comments section not interpret batch-file @ symbol as @reply reference

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

The `@ Symbol` is very common in Batch Scripts. Comments section mistakenly interprets it as an @reply comment. Here in this example Comment section thinks I'm referencing a user named `@echo` The image below shows what I mean.

[image]

My Current work-around is to place `@echo off` in double quotes. However that also leads to confusions sometime.

Is there any solution other than not referencing @User or putting the code starting with @ in double quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the batch script command in backticks (code quotes):

> @StefanFalk remove `@echo off`. You'll be able to see where things are going wrong.

This will means it won't get treated as an @mention and is a valid use for backticks. You can't circumvent the one @reply per comment limit as the text inside backticks isn't interpreted. So if you tried to type `@ChrisF` (say) to try to mention me as well I wouldn't see any notification from this.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF. I never thought about ``@echo off`` idea. In fact I just came to know I can place ``@echo`` or ``@User`` in backticks.

Comment: Guess. It works. Thanks again

Comment: You only need 1 back tick - anywhere in the comment.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari As you can see this works even though there are two @notifcations and one backtick `

Comment: That sounds good too.